# No consumible In-App Purchases in block (book/ comic)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am implementing an app to sell comic from my country, I have created non-consumable products in my tests works well.

My concern is that if I have 20 comics, each one I have to register as a non-consumer product?
There is an option to do it in block.

If within a month I add 5 new comic to my app, those 5 do I have to register them as a new consumable product each in itunnesconnect (appstoreconnect)?
[image: My app]

**Thanks, I hope some help to clear my doubts.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create products in groups, and each time you want to add another one it will be through an update of your app.